# How to ask where with calling function? - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to ask a Function in the where clause.
The code:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
 WHERE Field1=10
   and dbo.MyFunction(Field2,Field3,Field4) = NULL
```

And this returns me an empty table even though there are correct values in the table, why is this happening? What could be the reason?

Comment: Hint:  `IS NULL`, not `= NULL`.

Comment: Tanx! I tried a lot and did not understand why he did not work

Comment: If your function is tabular then you can't use in where clause

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
 WHERE Field1=10
   and dbo.MyFunction(Field2,Field3,Field4) **is** NULL
```

and not `= NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define like `dbo.MyFunction(Field2,Field3,Field4) is NULL` instead of `dbo.MyFunction(Field2,Field3,Field4) = NULL`

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
 WHERE Field1=10
   and dbo.MyFunction(Field2,Field3,Field4) is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you have to use `is null` or `is not null` instead `= null`.

I suggest you do not use function in your where clause it is not a good practice. You can use `cte` as below:

```
with
    cte
as
(
    select
        *   ,
        dbo.MyFunction(Field2,Field3,Field4)    as [your_function_field]
    from
        MyTable 
    where
        Field1=10
)
where
    [your_function_field] is null
```